# Can NSAutoPagination be relied on to cleanly divide an NSView into multiple pages?

Tags: cocoa, printing, document

I am writing a document-based cocoa app that allows users to print multi-page documents.  I am attempting to use cocoa's ability to essentially split a very tall NSView into a single column of identically-sized pages:

```
- (void)printDocumentWithSettings:(NSDictionary *)printSettings
                   showPrintPanel:(BOOL)showPrintPanel
                         delegate:(id)delegate
                 didPrintSelector:(SEL)didPrintSelector
                      contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    [self.printInfo setVerticallyCentered:0];
    [self.printInfo setHorizontallyCentered:0];

    [self.printInfo setHorizontalPagination:NSFitPagination];
    [self.printInfo setVerticalPagination:NSAutoPagination];

    [self.printInfo setRightMargin:0];
    [self.printInfo setLeftMargin:0];
    [self.printInfo setTopMargin:0];
    [self.printInfo setBottomMargin:0];

    NSPrintOperation *printOperation = 
        [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:self.printView];

    [printOperation runOperationModalForWindow:[self.printView window]
                                      delegate:nil
                                didRunSelector:nil
                                   contextInfo:nil];
}
```

The width of the view in question (self.printView) is exactly the width of the self.printInfo.paperSize, and the height is an exact multiple of  self.printInfo.paperSize.  So given that I have set all the printInfo margins to zero, when I call this:

```
[self.printInfo setVerticalPagination:NSAutoPagination];
```

I would expect the pages to be split perfectly into a single column, divided evenly at their borders.  However, when I print the document, the pagination is ever-so-slightly offset vertically.

The effect of this is that the first page appears to have a tiny amount of additional space at its bottom margin.  The second page appears slightly lower on the page than it should be, the third page even lower, and so on, until it goes completely haywire by about page six and looks nothing like the original printView.

This, in spite of the fact that I have verified my printView appears perfectly fine when viewed in its totality by using setVerticallyCentered:1 and setHorizontallyCentered:1 in a separate experiment.

I am aware of Apple's alternative (and more complex) approach to pagination, which involves subclassing NSView and overriding knowsPageRange: and rectForPage:, but I would prefer to avoid that unless there are known issues with the technique I'm using that make it unreliable.